# Can multer handle extremely large files to the tune of 3GB

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a NodeJS Backend Server that currently uses Busboy for chunked file uploads but for some reason I keep getting `sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=PUT` so I am thinking of using multer.

But I wanted to know, can multer handle extremely large file uploads to the tune of 3GB?

Answer (score 0):

> Node has a default max memory usage of less than 2GB

In the previous versions of Multer you couldn't upload a 3GB file on server because it used to keep the data on the memory and write it to a file specified in `dest` or `storage` option, however in new versions they support streaming data. (I haven't used it!)

Search for streaming parser tools for form-data and it should be fine. Don't know about Multer but [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) is going to help you for sure, also if you get Multer configuration right to stream chunks of data and write it on the disk you should be fine as well